# Driving in Slovakia with Uzbekistan driving licence

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, slovakia, uzbek-citizens

Family member came for a short term visit to stay in Slovakia. He has full driving licence issued in Uzbekistan (considered International licence).

1. Can Uzbekistan citizen with a licence drive a car with no additional documents?
2. Can Uzbekistan citizen drive with a copy/scan of the licence (in case they have lost/forgotten their licence)?

Car is registered to a Slovak citizen, with all documents in place.

Here is how the licence looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No you can't** use an Uzbek driving license to drive in Slovakia, you need to get an international driving permit. It doesn't matter if Uzbekistan considers it to be international, an IDP is a different document and is obtained separately. Of course, they still need their original driving license. The [US](https://slovakia.usembassy.gov/service/american-citizens-services/living-in-slovakia/driving-in-slovakia.html) embassy and [state](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/slovakia.html) department also advise people to get an IDP.

> [Requirements for tourists](http://www.slovak-republic.org/car/)
>
> A driving license issued in the United States or other foreign
>   countries is not valid in Slovakia until the driver does not have an
>   International Driving Licence.

Exact information is hard to find, but you could be [fined](http://www.mfa.bg/uploads/files/Embassies/Slovakia/TarifaMVR14EN.pdf) 30EUR or anywhere [between](http://trafficban.com/country.slovakia.goodtoknow.172.en.html) 67 and 332EUR for driving without the right documents. Note that police in Slovakia are allowed to fine you on the spot (but payment can be deferred).

As for using photocopies, from searching online there's no mention that they're accepted. Making copies is usually only good for backup or to submit forms, I wouldn't risk relying on that in case you get stopped or to try to rent a car.

Comment: If you have the info, what is the fine (consequences?) for driving with such licence?

Comment: @zx8754 you mean without a license ? I couldn't find authoritative info, but seems it can go [between](http://trafficban.com/country.slovakia.goodtoknow.172.en.html) 67 and 332 euros. Note that in Slovakia police can fine you on the spot

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As stated in the other answer, Uzbekistan is a signatory of the Vienna convention, and a such its licence is accepted. Note that USA is *not* a signatory.

Comment: Just noticed the answer below by Marina, do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Due to Vienna convention on road traffic 1949 and 1968 the UZ international driving licence is to be accepted.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic